# How to avoid the limit on the number of AND conditions for custom field (meta value) queries in WordPress get_posts()?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a search tool for a website built on WordPress and it seems like the `get_posts()` function in WordPress is limiting me to a maximum of 6 `AND` clauses for the meta value query, but I need the tool to take much more than 6 AND clauses.

Below is an example of my query that is returning an empty array. Code 1 below is the `print_r()` of the array I am passing to `get_posts()` that returns an empty array. Code 2 below is identical to code 1 but I removed one `AND` statement and it returns a result. Note I have tried multiple combinations this is just one example.

For avoidance of doubt I have also included an example of a post in the database (as Code 3 below) that should match code 1 so I think we can rule out the fact that the query is not matching anything. This leads me to believe that `get_posts()` can only handle up to 6 `AND` clauses in the meta query. Or maybe I am missing something? Can I force `get_posts()` to work with more than 6 `AND` clauses?

Code 1:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => page
    [posts_per_page] => 10000
    [category_name] => active-cards
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_purchase_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 46
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_balance_transfer_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 14
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_rewards_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_air_points_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_frequent_flyer_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_brand
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => amex
                            [1] => mastercard
                            [2] => visa
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_provider
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => anz
                            [1] => asb
                            [2] => bnz
                            [3] => westpac
                            [4] => kiwibank
                            [5] => tsb
                            [6] => warehouse_money
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

)
```

Code 2:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => page
    [posts_per_page] => 10000
    [category_name] => active-cards
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_purchase_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 46
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_balance_transfer_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 14
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_rewards_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_air_points_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_frequent_flyer_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_brand
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => amex
                            [1] => mastercard
                            [2] => visa
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

)
```

Code 3 (this is an example of the post returned by code 2.  Code 1 should also match this item but it returns nothing.

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3742
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2017-01-17 20:01:36
            [post_date_gmt] => 2017-01-17 09:01:36
            [post_title] => Westpac Airpoints Business MasterCard Credit Card
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => westpac-airpoints-business-mastercard-credit-card
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2017-04-11 22:08:20
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-04-11 11:08:20
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://www.creditcardscompare.co.nz/?page_id=3742
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => page
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [meta] => Array
                (

                    [card_annual_fee] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 145
                        )

                    [card_purchase_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20.95
                        )


                    [card_balance_transfer_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1.99
                        )


                    [card_cash_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 22.95
                        )


                    [card_interest_free_days] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44
                        )

                    [card_provider] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Westpac
                        )

                    [card_brand] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Mastercard
                        )


                    [is_rewards_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_low_interest_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_no_annual_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_student_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_prestige_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_air_new_zealand_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_air_points_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_frequent_flyer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_airpoint_lounge_access_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_best_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_black_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_business_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )


                    [is_cash_advance_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_cash_back_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_cheap_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_debit_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_flybuys_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_gold_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_high_income_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_home_loan_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_instant_approval_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_long_term_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_low_annual_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_low_income_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_no_foreign_transaction_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_platinum_card?] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_purchase_protection_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_qantas_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_signup_bonus_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_travel_insurance_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_zero_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_zero_interest_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [card_star_rating] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                        )

                )

            [post_url] => http://www.creditcardscompare.co.nz/westpac-airpoints-business-mastercard-credit-card/
        )
```

As requested by here is the WP_query SQL

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (78)
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'card_purchase_rate' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '30' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'card_balance_transfer_rate' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '13' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'is_rewards_card' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt3.meta_key = 'is_air_points_card' AND mt3.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt4.meta_key = 'is_frequent_flyer_card' AND mt4.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' )
  ) 
  AND 
  ( mt5.meta_key = 'card_brand' AND mt5.meta_value IN ('amex','mastercard','visa') ) 
  AND 
  ( mt6.meta_key = 'card_provider' AND mt6.meta_value IN ('anz','asb','bnz','westpac','kiwibank','tsb','warehouse_money') )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10000
```

Comment: please share your full query  with meta code.

Comment: Hi Shital. Thanks for your help btw. I have added the WP_Query SQL to the original post as it is too long to include as a comment

Answer (score 0):

you can create your WP query by using "WP_Query" with meta.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

For Ex:

```
$page_args=array(
            'type'                     => "page",
            'post_status'              => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'           => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'         => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                 array(
                    'key' => 'card_balance_transfer_rate',
                    'value' => array( "0", "14" ),
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                )
             )
        );
        $page_my_query = null;
        $page_my_query = new WP_Query($page_args);

        if( $page_my_query->have_posts() ) 
        {

            while ($page_my_query->have_posts()) : $page_my_query->the_post(); 
                the_title();
             endwhile;

        }
        wp_reset_query($page_my_query);
```

Comment: I have tried that - it doesn't work for more than 6nested AND statements. Actually get_posts() uses WP_Query() too

Comment: please share your query

Comment: Please see sql query added into the original post

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the meta query limitation as well here...

[WordPress Meta Query With Post Status "publish" is Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774048/wordpress-meta-query-with-post-status-publish-is-not-working)

I wish I could upvote your question because the limitation isn't well-documented. Thank you for your contribution.

Your question made me realize the problem was that WP_Query limited the number of meta query clauses in a single WP_Query.

Writing your own SQL query is a good solution. I decided to use manual filtering at the application level since it is a back-end function not dependent on performance.

**Solution:**

There seems to be a limit of 5 meta queries, though setting the post status to 'draft' seemed to allow 6 meta queries, which is even more unusual and likely related to some kind of conflict/side-effect of WP_Query.

I was able to remove one of the meta query clauses and manually filter the results.

The choice of clauses to manually filter should be dependent on what clause would work with the smallest data set.