# WordPress WP_Query Limited to 5 Meta Query Clauses

Tags: wordpress, meta

The query works if you change "publish" to "draft" or remove the source clause. These are args passed to the WP_Query constructor. I immediately count the results to verify that WP_Query is in fact returning no results. I checked the data in the database and made sure the data is congruent.

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => post
    [post_status] => Array
        (
            [0] => publish
        )

    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [view_count_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _viewcount
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [actual_date_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _actualdate
                )

            [start_date_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _actualdate
                    [value] => 2021-03-23 00-00-00
                    [compare] => >
                )

            [end_date_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _actualdate
                    [value] => 2021-03-24 00-00-00
                    [compare] => <
                )

            [color_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _color
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                    [compare] => IN
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                        )

                )

            [source_clause] => Array
                (
                    [key] => _sourcename
                    [value] => AHA
                    [compare] => =
                )

        )

    [orderby] => Array
        (
            [actual_date_clause] => DESC
        )

)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what is the problem without you showing your actual WP_Query request

Comment: related question here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556074/how-to-avoid-the-limit-on-the-number-of-and-conditions-for-custom-field-meta-va

these questions should be upvoted since the meta query limitations of wp_query aren't well documented.

Comment: solution: there seems to be a limit of 5 meta queries, though setting the post status to draft seemed to allow 6 meta queries, which is even more unusual. i was able to remove one of the meta query clauses when using the source clause and manually filter by the removed meta query clause. the choice of clauses to manually filter should be dependent on what clause would work with the smallest data set.

Answer (score 0):

Related question here.... [How to avoid the limit on the number of AND conditions for custom field (meta value) queries in WordPress get_posts()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556074/how-to-avoid-the-limit-on-the-number-of-and-conditions-for-custom-field-meta-va)

Problem:

WP_Query limits meta query clauses to five meta clauses. If you have 6 meta query clauses, you will get no results.

Solution 1:

Write your own SQL query. Example provided by the related question.

Solution 2:

Remove excess meta queries beyond the 5 meta query limit for WP_Query and manually filter results. Choice of meta queries to be removed should be based on whatever would result in the smallest data set.